Access local server by name in file explorer
I have a server at work with shared folders for several terminal pc to access.
One of the terminals suddenly stopped being able to access the shared folders. The situation is like this:

The pc CAN access the shared folders using the ip address instead of the server name.
The pc CAN ping the server by both ip address and name.
Other programs like remote desktop CAN locate the server by name.

It's only file explorer that is unable to access the server by name. I reset the network, DNS, and added the server to the hosts file, and still is unable to access it.
I looked for similar issues, but none seem to have the server naming issue specifically on  file explorer only.
UPDATE: file explorer no longer recognizes the servers ip address, so i cant access it that way either.
I tested to see if the computer can access another terminal thats in the local network. It can access shared folders on other terminals just fine. Its just the server's address that it refuses to recognize. I also checked to see if the server itself can access shared folders in this faulty terminal. It cannot, so the problem goes both ways. Again, they can ping each other and use rdp, its just the file explorer that wont work.

is the windows Firewall enabled? if yes, please disable it for testing or allow the private subnet, moreover verify that not the public network is defined as it would usually disallow the access to the smb share

Firewall is disabled. It still doesnt connect

then usually the dns resolution is screwed, use either the ip or reinstall the client
